# Plot more than one variable that supports extendTrace using plotly-js

Tags: javascript, html, plot, plotly

The following code can plot one variable (say x) real-time plot using plotly-js.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="navbar"><span>Real-Time Chart with Plotly.js</span></div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="chart"></div>
        <script>
            function getDatax() {
                return Math.random();
            }  
            function getDatay() {
                return Math.random();
            } 
            function getDataz() {
                return Math.random();
            }
            Plotly.plot('chart',[{
                y:[getDatax()],
                type:'line'
            }]);

            var cnt = 0;
            setInterval(function(){
                Plotly.extendTraces('chart',{ y:[[getDatax()]]}, [0]);
                cnt++;
                if(cnt > 500) {
                    Plotly.relayout('chart',{
                        xaxis: {
                            range: [cnt-500,cnt]
                        }
                    });
                }
            },15);
        </script>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, my question is, if I want to plot y and z in the same graph and in the same manner, which lines should I need to modify ?

I have changed

```
 Plotly.plot('chart',[{
                y:[getDatax(),getDatay(),getDataz()],
                type:'line'
            }]);

            var cnt = 0;
            setInterval(function(){
                Plotly.extendTraces('chart',{ y:[[getDatax()],[getDatay()],[getDataz()]});
```

But the graph came out was incorrect. What were my mistakes? What would be the correct code to plot 3 variables simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean to have multiple lines for your chart then this helps

```js
function getDatax() {
  return Math.random();
}

function getDatay() {
  return Math.random();
}

function getDataz() {
  return Math.random();
}
Plotly.plot('chart', [{
  y: [getDatax(), getDatax(), getDatax(), getDatax(), getDatax(), getDatax()],
  type: 'line'
}, {
  y: [getDataz(), getDataz(), getDataz(), getDataz(), getDataz()],
  type: 'line'
}]);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar"><span>Real-Time Chart with Plotly.js</span></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="chart"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

To make it realtime:

```js
function getDatax() {
  return Math.random();
}

function getDatay() {
  return Math.random();
}

function getDataz() {
  return Math.random();
}
Plotly.plot('chart', [{
  y: [getDatax(), getDatax(), getDatax(), getDatax(), getDatax(), getDatax()],
  type: 'line'
}, {
  y: [getDataz(), getDataz(), getDataz(), getDataz(), getDataz()],
  type: 'line'
}]);
var cnt = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  Plotly.extendTraces('chart', {
    y: [
      [getDatax()]
    ]
  }, [0]);
  Plotly.extendTraces('chart', {
    y: [
      [getDataz()]
    ]
  }, [1]);
  cnt++;
  if (cnt > 500) {
    Plotly.relayout('chart', {
      xaxis: {
        range: [cnt - 500, cnt]
      }
    });
  }
}, 15);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar"><span>Real-Time Chart with Plotly.js</span></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="chart"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope that helps you

Comment: Hi.... Thank you so much. It works perfectly. May I ask you a question regarding the code... what is the logic behind 6 getDatax() and 5 getDataz(). Will it affect the outcome if I make them of equal number?

Comment: There is no specific logic. I just used your code as provided. I expect that your data will be more complex and that(equal numbers) should not matter

Comment: Ohh I see. Yeah, they consists non-linear equations.:/
Anyway, thank you so much for you kind help. :)